# Can I use What's up as the meaning of What's the problem?

Tags: spoken-english

like if someone tryna fight me then can I use the word sup as the meaning of what's your problem?

Comment: Please don't use SMS style writing in your posts (it's "trying to", not "tryna"). Also, the question you've asked doesn't match the title. Please edit your question to be self consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no.

It is true that "what's up?" can be a way of asking someone who appears distressed or upset if they are alright - so in that sense it can be used to determine if there is a "problem". However, in most contexts, "what's up?" and the slang abbreviation "'sup?" are idiomatic ways of casually asking "how are you?". Like the similar "what's happening?", it can also idiomatically mean "what have you been doing recently?"

Similarly, "what's the problem?" can be a benign way of enquiring if somebody has a difficulty, and can even tacitly imply an offer to help with a problem. In colloqiual use though, "what's the problem?" or "what's *your* problem?" are ways of responding to a threat, aggression, or passive aggression.

For your specific example of somebody trying to pick a fight with you, the most idiomatic response would be "what's *your* problem?" - although not necessarily the *wisest* response, if I might add.